# Periodicity of the solution of the wave equation

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, differential-equations

In a few references, I have found that if I have a wave equation
$$
\nabla^2 E=\left[\frac{n(x,t)}{c}\right]^2\frac{\partial^2E}{\partial t^2}
$$

where the refractive index is periodic in space and time

$$
n(x+\Lambda,t)=n(x,t) \\
n(x,t+T)=n(x,t)
$$

then, also the electric field $E(x,t)$ has the same periodicity. How can I prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement in question is the basis of *Floquet theorem* or *Bloch theorem*, depending on the application (the former is usually used in nonlinear theory, while the latter is the name used in condensed matter physics). This theorem not only states the periodicity of the solution, but also proposes its specific form.

The periodicity is easily verified by checking that $E(x + n\Lambda, t + mT)$, where $n,m$ are arbitrary integers, is the solution of the same equation.
Indeed , the change of variables $x \longrightarrow x + n\Lambda, t \longrightarrow t + mT$ leads us to equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} E(x + n\Lambda, t + mT)
=
\left[\frac{n(x + n\Lambda, t + mT)}{c}\right]^2
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} E(x + n\Lambda, t + mT).
\end{equation}
However the periodicity of $n(x,t)$ means that this is identical with 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} E(x + n\Lambda, t + mT)
=
\left[\frac{n(x,t)}{c}\right]^2
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} E(x + n\Lambda, t + mT),
\end{equation}
which means that 
$E(x + n\Lambda, t + mT)$ is identical with $E(x, t)$.

Comment: I actually thought at the proof you wrote using the change of variables, but there is something that does not convince me: since you pointed out that this problem can be solved using the Floquet theorem (thank you for this!), the solution should be the a plane wave times a periodic function. From the proof above, though, it looks like all the solution should have the same periodicity, not only a part of it. Sorry if it's a dumb question!

Comment: Good point! I suppose I had to be more rigorous: a periodic solution does solve this equation, as I have shown. But the solution does not have to be periodic: you can use a Floquet/Bloch form. Note however, that the periodic function in Floquet/Bloch theorem generally satisfies a different equation - it becomes identical with the initial equation only when the plane wave has zero frequency. This is the equation that you will obtain by substituting Floquet solution into your equation.

Comment: Yes, Floquet's equation is indeed different, but the result of the theorem can be replicated here. What I just did here is doing the same calculation for the proof of Floquet's theorem (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Floquet%27s_Theorem proof 1) and I noticed that I can get again a result that is the product of periodic function times a plane wave. Just, this time, the plane wave depends on both time and space! I dis this because of your hint of using Floquet's theory, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is because electric field is function of medium refractive index :
$$
\mathbf {E} (n(z,t)) =\operatorname {Re} \!\left[\mathbf {E} _{0}e^{i(2\pi (n(z,t)+i\kappa )z/\lambda _{0}-\omega t)}\right]
$$